# Change controller Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, controller, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm trying to customize my dashboard of Sonata but although I can change the layout, I can't make the controller to be the one I want (and with that pass some other values). So sonata always loads the default on the CoreController and not the one that I want. Can you tell me what I have to do for changing the controller for the one I want?

This is a part of my config.yml:

```
sonata_admin:
   title_logo: bundles/ebuigui/images/brand.png
    templates:
        dashboard: EBUIBackendBundle:CRUD:adminView.html.twig
        list: EBUIBackendBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig
        edit: EBUIBackendBundle:CRUD:create.html.twig
    dashboard:
        blocks:
        # display a dashboard block
        - { position: left, type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list }

sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        # Enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's better that you use eventListener to modif the logic of Sonata CoreController. If you want to override the core controller you can reffer to [a question asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937235/symfony2-overriding-createaction-in-sonataadmin)